# Javascript using a function Number() inside map() function to convert string to a number

Tags: javascript, function, dictionary, reduce

I want to convert the imdb ratings given inside the array of objects watchList. I am trying it using map function but it is not happening. The newList is giving just the old list with no changes whatever. What am I doing wrong?

```
var watchList = [
                {  

                   "Metascore": "74",
                   "imdbRating": "8.8",
                   "imdbVotes": "1,446,708",
                   "imdbID": "tt1375666",
                   "Type": "movie",
                   "Response": "True"
                },
                {  
                   "Metascore": "74",
                   "imdbRating": "8.6",
                   "imdbVotes": "910,366",
                   "imdbID": "tt0816692",
                   "Type": "movie",
                   "Response": "True"
                },
                {
                   "Metascore": "82",
                   "imdbRating": "9.0",
                   "imdbVotes": "1,652,832",
                   "imdbID": "tt0468569",
                   "Type": "movie",
                   "Response": "True"
                }
];



let newList=[];
newList=watchList.map(function(list){
  Number(list.imdbRating);
  return list;
});
console.log(newList);
```

Comment: `Number(list.imdbRating);` creates a Number ... then you ignore the result

Comment: try `list.imdbRating = Number(list.imdbRating);`

Answer (score 1):

Just declaring `Number` does not mutate the original value. If you want the object's property to have its `imdbRating` be a Number, you have to *assign* it.

```js
var watchList=[{"Metascore":"74","imdbRating":"8.8","imdbVotes":"1,446,708","imdbID":"tt1375666","Type":"movie","Response":"True"},{"Metascore":"74","imdbRating":"8.6","imdbVotes":"910,366","imdbID":"tt0816692","Type":"movie","Response":"True"},{"Metascore":"82","imdbRating":"9.0","imdbVotes":"1,652,832","imdbID":"tt0468569","Type":"movie","Response":"True"}];

watchList.forEach(function(list){
  list.imdbRating = Number(list.imdbRating);
});
console.log(watchList);
```

Note that objects are passed by reference in Javascript - changing something in a reference to an object will change the original object, which is why I used `forEach` instead of `.map`. If you want to create entirely new objects (and not mutate the original ones), use object spread as well as `map`:

```js
var watchList=[{"Metascore":"74","imdbRating":"8.8","imdbVotes":"1,446,708","imdbID":"tt1375666","Type":"movie","Response":"True"},{"Metascore":"74","imdbRating":"8.6","imdbVotes":"910,366","imdbID":"tt0816692","Type":"movie","Response":"True"},{"Metascore":"82","imdbRating":"9.0","imdbVotes":"1,652,832","imdbID":"tt0468569","Type":"movie","Response":"True"}];

const newList = watchList.map(({ imdbRating, ...rest }) => ({
  imdbRating: Number(imdbRating),
  ...rest,
}));
console.log(newList);
```

Comment: I'd highlight the fact that you (correctly) use `forEach` rather than the inappropriate `map` :p

Comment: but fail for having the `forEach` make an unnecessasry `return`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick conversion from string to integer you can use `+` operator.

Example :

```
var newList=[];
newList=watchList.map(function(list){
    list.imdbRating = +list.imdbRating;  
    return list;
});
```